# How to pass enum value in hasura query in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, hasura, flutter-graphql

So I am trying to query data from hasura but one of the variable that I am passing is a variable due to which it always gives some error I tried many different solutions [like this](https://github.com/zino-hofmann/graphql-flutter/issues/515)
but no solution so far this is the query

```
query MyQuery {
Product(where: {product_category: {_eq: Liquor}}) {
product_decription
product_category
product_id
product_img
product_name
product_price
}
}
```

and this is the query part that I am trying

```
QueryOptions quer = QueryOptions(
  document: gql(r'''query MyQuery($category:[ProductType_enum!]) {
 Product(where: {product_category: {_eq: $category}}) {
product_category
product_decription
product_id
product_img
product_name
product_price
}
}
'''),
  variables: <String, dynamic>{
    'category': ['Liquor']
  });
```

I am not able to understand what's wrong I am doing in this query
this is the enum class

```
enum Product_type {
Toiletries,
Liquor,
Household_Requisites,
General_Items,
Food_Medecine,
Watches_Stationery
}
```

I am getting this error

> OperationException (OperationException(linkException: null, graphqlErrors: [GraphQLError(message: variable "category" is declared as [ProductType_enum!], but used where ProductType_enum is expected, locations: null, path: null, extensions: {path: $.selectionSet.Product.args.where.product_category._eq, code: validation-failed})]))

for normal query it works fine .

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? If possible please update the question with the Stacktrace

Comment: @RohanThacker i have updated the question with more details let me know if you can help me

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava I believe I have provided the answer you are looking for. Were you able to check to see if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing an array where a single value is expected. The important part of the error message is this:

`variable "category" is declared as [ProductType_enum!], but used where ProductType_enum is expected`

In this case `[ProductType_enum!]` represents an array but the `_eq` part of your query is expecting a single value.

Just update your variables to be 'category': 'Liquor' and it should work for you.

If you want to be able to pass an array you should use `_in` instead of `_eq` and then write your query as

```
query MyQuery($categories:[ProductType_enum!]) {
 Product(where: {product_category: {_in: $categories}})
```

Comment: Hey sorry For late reply and it can work with _eq also if i pass it as string

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that it was able to help you out